# Highlight output in terminal emulator

Tags: terminal-emulator

Can't imagine I'm the first one to wonder, but I really can't find anything on this - maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms.

I'm looking for a terminal emulator that would allow me to navigate through the output like a text file using the keyboard. There are some really good ways to do this inside Emacs. Specifically the FANTASTIC multi-term package which lets you switch between text/terminal mode very easily, but running terminals inside emacs isn't very lightweight.

I'd love something that is exactly like xterm or xrvt but allows you to do something similar. Suggestions?

Comment: screen and tmux do this

Comment: Screen and tmux do this, but Emacs do it better.

Comment: How is the title of your post related to the post itself? You ask nothing about highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite) is a very nice lightweight terminal that has keybindings to allow you to scroll through the output buffer as well as to select and copy text all with or without using a mouse.

Otherwise you can use screen or tmux to give you this functionally in any terminal.

Comment: Termite provided thorough satisfaction. What an elegant little piece of software, exactly what I was looking for.